# How to selectively multiply or add columns in pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python-2.7, lambda, pandas, generator, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like the one below:

```
Sample    P1    P2    P3
A         0.25  0.5   0.25
B         0.25  0     0.25
C         0.25  0.25  0
```

I would like to be able to selectively only multiply the P columns if they are not equal to zero, and output a 5th column of multiplied values. It should look like the following:

```
Sample    P1    P2    P3    Multiplied
A         0.25  0.5   0.25  0.03125
B         0.25  0     0.25  0.0625
C         0.25  0.25  0     0.0625
```

I'm not quite sure how to write the code for this. Is there any advice for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to throw out an alternative (you can use the [`prod`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.prod.html) DataFrame method):

```
In [11]: df['multiplied'] = df[df != 0].prod(axis=1)

In [12]: df
Out[12]: 
          P1    P2    P3  multiplied
Sample                              
A       0.25  0.50  0.25     0.03125
B       0.25  0.00  0.25     0.06250
C       0.25  0.25  0.00     0.06250
```

Answer (score 3):

```
In [120]: df['multiplied'] = np.prod(df[df!=0].fillna(1).values,axis=1)

In [121]: df
Out[121]: 
          P1    P2    P3  multiplied
Sample                              
A       0.25  0.50  0.25     0.03125
B       0.25  0.00  0.25     0.06250
C       0.25  0.25  0.00     0.06250
```

Comment: Could also replace the 0s with `NaNs` ahead of time and call `prod` on that.

Comment: @TomAugspurger or use the DataFrame prod method :)

Comment: @AndyHayden Even easier.